# LWJGL - how to properly read input events?

Tags: java, input, lwjgl

I'm not sure if this is the right way, please correct me if it's not:

In main loop, I poll events like this:

```
Keyboard.poll();
Mouse.poll();
// process the events
```

Then at the end of the main loop, I have `Display.update()` to swap buffers etc, and `Display.sync(60)` to keep FPS.

Now the question is, since `Display.update()` apparently also polls inputs, does this mean I'm going to lose some events? Should I remove the additional poll's and rely on `Display.update()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call Display.update(false), which does not poll inputs. However if you do, poll by calling Display.processMessages(), not individual devices.

Comment: Yeah I've meanwhile found this myself, thanks anyway.